# String Replacement in VBS

Tags: vbscript

I need to replace "." with "˙", im not sure how to do this in VBS, in ruby its gsub(".","˙") but i cant find anything to do this in VBS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
REPLACE(str, ".", "&dot;")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is called [Replace](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_replace.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the MSDN on the Replace function in VBS

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5(v=vs.90).aspx

And here is w3schools

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_replace.asp

```
Replace(string,find,replacewith[,start[,count[,compare]]])
```